# Android app with unity:Failed to open render node no suh file or directory

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unity-game-engine, mobile

I created an android application in kotlin that also contains a unity project that needs to be opened through unityPlayer. When I call unity, I get the error Failed to open rendernode. and application crash

I try to open unity project in kotlin app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.